# PHP MYSQL QUERY EXECUTION

Tags: php, mysql

I framed the below mysql query and it showing T_VARIABLE error, can anybody correct the below code

```
$sql8 ="insert into followup_messages (id, chat_id, first_name, last_name, message) values ('$followuptaskid','".$row9['chat_id']."','".$row9['first_name'].'","'.$row9['last_name'].'", '$closurecomments')";
```

Comment: Don't patch your query together like this. Use prepared statements. Then your error will go away too since it is probably due to an user input string that cripples your query.

Comment: The problem is that you're inconsistent about whether you're using double quotes or single quotes around the PHP strings that you're concatenating.

Comment: The problem is you're using the result of one query to construct another one. It's just not necessary. You only need one query.

Comment: that error is because your quotes are messed up, but as said above, you need to use a prepare statement and not use php variables directly in a sql string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parameterized queries to help prevent SQL injection attacks.

```
 // $con is your mysqli_connection
 // I created 3 variables from your above code and escaped them, you will need to protect the other 2 pieces of data being inserted as well.
 
 <?php
 $chat_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['chat_id']);
 $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['first_name']);
 $last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['last_name']);

 $insert = mysqli_prepare($con, "insert into followup_messages (id,chat_id,first_name,last_name,message) values (?,?,?,?,?)");
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($insert, "sssss", $followuptaskid,$chat_id,$first_name,$last_name,$closurecomments);
 mysqli_stmt_execute($insert);
 ?>
```

Comment: Thank you all, I have rectified the mistake and corrected the code as advised